# Origin of the Inverse Mean Curvature Flow (IMCF)

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature, history

I was reading [The Inverse Mean Curvature Flow and the Riemannian Penrose Inequality](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1090349447) by Gerhard Huisken and Tom Ilmanen and it is stated on page $7$ that

> Geroch [30] introduced the inverse mean curvature flow and discovered that the Hawking mass of the evolving surface is monotone nondecreasing, provided that the surface is connected and the scalar curvature of M is nonnegative.

The reference [30] is

> [30] R. Geroch, Energy extraction, Ann. New York Acad. Sci. 224 (1973) 108–17,

which is available [here](http://strangebeautiful.com/other-texts/geroch-energy-extraction.pdf).

The problem is that there isn't a formal mathematical definition about the IMCF in the Geroch's paper and I can't see anything which induce to think in define IMCF in this paper. Can anyone explain how "Geroch [30] introduced the inverse mean curvature flow"?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: I am not a physicist, I'm a mathematician with no background in advanced topics of physics, so I would like to, if it's possible, a full explanation with references to physics's background.

Comment: See Appendix there is definition $\phi =p^{-1}$ before equation (8).

Comment: @AlexTrounev, thanks for answer and sorry for taking so long to answer, but I has a doubt about the definition of $\phi$ given. What means $\phi \xi^a \nabla_a t = 1$ in the definition of $\phi$? I think it's some physical notation that I don't know and I couldn't understand this equality.